# How to generate an all in one WordPress New content, plugin and theme update report on a website?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

I am sure people must have tried this already but I am not able to find any good resources or guidance on how to create a complete report of a WordPress website weekly or monthly.

A report that would list new and updated plugins, new and updated pages, posts, custom posts and WordPress core updates implemented.

Please let me know if you can find a resource, plugin or if you have tried this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to use a plugin for this, I think [WP CLient Reports](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-client-reports/) is exactly what you are after. It can create periodical reports for you about plugin, theme or core updates, as well as post/pages updates, etc.

[image: WP Client Reports dashboard]

Comment: Hi, this is great. Thank you. I will take a look at this now.